# how to use custom attribute in chef, so one can pass some value in default recipe?

Tags: attributes, chef-infra

What I am trying to do pass two values
input1, and input2 to recipe/default.rb.

These values comes from jason file. Now I use these input to parse my template xml.

```
template "/tmp/temp_chef_sample.xml" do
  source "temp_chef_sample.xml.erb"
  variables( :fsIP => node[:hostname], :fsname => node[:ipaddress], :path=>    node[:input1], :value=> node[:input2] )
end
```

I have two question.

1. how can I add attribute "path" and "value" in attribute list?
2. how can I populate them without using json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set node attributes in many places.

The cookbook's attributes files

```
# cookbook/attributes/filename.rb
...
node.default[:input1] = 'somevalue'
...
```

The environment, role, or Node object

```
....
"default_attributes": {
  "input1": "somevalue"
}
....
```